# ArcMap suddenly started exporting massive .png files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, png

I'm exporting a very simple map. It has a single polygon shapefile on top of ESRI base imagery. There are several text boxes as well, but just simple Arial text.

I'm exporting to .png at 220 DPI and the file size is huge - 19MB. I've exported many similar maps and they are usually between 1 and 4MB. Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: You might check the page size you are exporting to?

Comment: Also check resolution

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that would change the size of the PNG by that magnitude, assuming your DPI has always been 220, and the vectors are generally similar, would be the page size being larger. 1-4MB is typical for an 8.5"x11" paper, but something larger like 14" x 22" could conceivably generate a PNG around 20MB.

If the page size is the same, then I'd try out the old stand-by: Reboot your computer!